# Can someone help me identify what the value of this capacitor is?

Tags: capacitor, identification, component-values

I have an older computer and as I was pulling the graphics card my fingers slipped and I pulled this off the board... Problem is I can't find one with the same markings so I need to find a replacement... Any help that won't involve me spending a horrible amount of money on a new board (as everything else is still good) would be amazing.

Markings are:
361
100
2 5z (there is a space here between the 2 and the five) 
Thanks [image]

Comment: The part itself may still be OK.  It may have pulled out of the solder on the pads.  It may, however, have taken the pads with it when you tore it off. Look at the bottom side, and look at the pads where it belongs.

Comment: I voted to close as the answer to that old question includes a datasheet that explains the codes on the parts

Comment: The pads are fine it pulled from inside the cap itself thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

It is a 100uF 25v electrolytic.  The black mark denotes the negative connection.

Comment: Thanks man :) I looked up the datasheet (or several) but couldn't make heads or tails of it lol